# Content Gallery Layout

Tags: css, layout, gallery

I'm trying to create a simple gallery utilizing the layout in this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8juB3.jpg). When a viewer navigates to the page, I'd like them to initially see text/image content in the main box and images in the smaller box. If the viewer clicks on one of the smaller boxes, I would like the content in the main box to change accordingly.

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great, thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="something.jpg" onclick="changeX1()" /> //That's an example of the img tag on HTML:
<div id="gallery">Initial text</div> //This is the place where the big image will be shown, initially with text.
```

Javascript:

```
var x=0
var y=document.getElementById("gallery");
}
function changeX_1(){
    x=1
    changePic();
}

function changePic(){
    switch (x){
        case 1:
            y.style.innerHTML="";
            y.style.backgroundImage="url(something)";
            break;    
    }
}
```

What I've done is, made 2 variables: x and y. 'x' will be the picture number and 'y' will be the background. When you click on an image, the 'x' will change, the y's innerHTML will be deleted and the background image will be changed.

I only used 1 image in the example, a real gallery will be made of much more. for each photo you add you'll need a new "changeX" function and another case.

If you don't know javascript you should learn :)

***EDIT:***

```
var x=0
var y=document.getElementById("gallery");
}
function changeX1(){
    x=1
    changePic();
}
function changeX2(){
    x=2
    changePic();
}


function changePic(){
    switch (x){
        case 1:
            y.style.innerHTML="";
            y.style.backgroundImage="url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Flag-Lookbookcolor.jpg?7024)";
            break;    
        case 2:
            y.style.innerHTML="";
            y.style.backgroundImage="url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Flag-Videocolor.jpg?7178)";
            break;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes. I'm also thinking I might be able to accomplish the same thing using remote linking (http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/12/how-to-create-pure-css-rollover-to-display-single-or-multiple-elements-at-remote-area/)

Comment: I'm using Shopify to build this site and for some reason when I add <img src="something.jpg" onclick="changeX1" /> to the html editor and save, the 'onclick="changeX1" keeps disappearing...I wonder if this is a glitch with their system.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my bad. It should be onclick="changeX1()". I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it still isn't working. Sorry to be so difficult, I know enough Javascript to be able to read through a script and get what it's doing, but not enough to really troubleshoot or start from scratch. I'm trying to learn! Here's the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9B8H/41/ No CSS and I just threw in some placeholder images.

Comment: You didn't get it. Look at the code I posted and I guess you'll understand better. The 'div' should be where the pictures are shown, not the 'img' tags.